# Check Username availability from two tables c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I am trying to check username availability from two table how can I do this Please help.

```
            a = (from n in dbobj.stores 
                 where n.st_UserName == storeuname 
                 select n.st_id).Single();
            return true;
```

I am trying to check at same time like:

```
            a = (from n in dbobj.stores && dbobj.customer
           where n.st_UserName == storeuname or n.cu_UserName == storeuname
                 select n.st_id).Single();
            return true;
```

Help Me if I am doing anything in wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Single` assumes that always one record will be returned. According to Microsoft:

> Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence.

So better use `Any` and then adapt the return-statement

```
bool any = (from n in dbobj.stores 
            where n.st_UserName == storeuname 
            select n.st_id).Any();
return any;
```

In the second query you are apparently trying to concatenate two tables. You cannot do it like this. Instead perform the tests one after the other

```
bool any = (from n in dbobj.stores 
            where n.st_UserName == storeuname 
            select n.st_id).Any();
if (any) {
    return true;
}

any = (from n in dbobj.customer
       where n.cu_UserName == storeuname
       select n.st_id).Any();
return any;
```

This second table will only be queried if the user is not found in the first one.

Comment: can you please tell me how I can check  username in two tables of database

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also, why use `Count()` when `Any()`gives you a `bool` response?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't *literally* check two tables *at the same time*, but you can check both *in one query*.  There are many ways to do that - the most straightforward way is to `Union` two queries:

```
a = 
    (from n in dbobj.stores 
                     where n.st_UserName == storeuname 
                     select n.st_id)
    .Union
    (from n in dbobj.stores 
                     where  n.cu_UserName == storeuname 
                     select n.st_id)
    .Single()
```